# Null characters in output from USB

Tags: arduino, usb, python

I'm getting null-bytes in the output from an Arduino Mega 2560, when delaying reading from the USB buffer for e.g. 5 seconds. Can anyone explain why this happens and what I can do to mitigate the nulls? I assume its related to the input buffer being filled up. Thank you in advance.

Arduino program which spams data:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("a");
}
```

Python program which delays reading data for 5 seconds and then starts reading:

```
import time
from serial import Serial

serial = Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=115200)
if serial.is_open:
    serial.close()
serial.open()

time.sleep(5)

try:
    while True:
        bytes_line = serial.readline()
        if b'\x00' in bytes_line:
            print(bytes_line)
finally:
    serial.close()
```

Prints this:

```
b'\x00a\r\n'
b'a\r\x00\n'
b'a\x00\r\n'
```

Inspecting the packets with Wireshark, shows this around the time it starts reading:
[image]

The first URB packet (193) contains HEX 62 which is reported as null by python.
Run on Ubuntu 20.04, kernel 5.11.0-25-generic, Python3.6.

Comment: why are you messing with USB packets? ... your interface is a serial port

Comment: @jsotola Can you elaborate? I'm seeing nulls in the data read in python. I confirm that they occur right around the time the USB stops polling for data. I'm inspecting the packets, not messing with them? This is a minimal reproduce of the issue.

Comment: `messing with` means `inspecting`, `bothering with`, `working with`, etc.  ... your connection is through a serial port ... how that translates to the USB packet content is irrelevant .. it is serial data at one end and serial data at the other end

Comment: Sounds like there is a bug in the UART to USB chip or the driver for it.  Since there is neither hardware nor software flow control it is possible to lose data if the data isn't being read fast enough, but random NUL bytes is not nice.

Comment: @OskarSkog So do you believe it is on the Arduino side?